# How can I save data from Sharepoint Extension?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I am currently creating a SharePoint extension (with spfx), 
At the first lauch of the extension, I have one registration form (7 input, type string).

How can I save this data on the sharepoint site so the users can read them?

I can't use the property bag of the site because I am using modern sites, by default, scripting is disabled so I can't write data in the property bag.

Do you have a solution, a workaround, an idea to solve my problem?

Thank you :-)

Comment: how about using SharePoint list ? you can do CRUD operations on it !

Comment: I already thought about that one but I just need to save one data and it's not very optimized :/

Answer (score 1):

Use [PnP library](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items).

```
import { default as pnp, ItemAddResult } from "sp-pnp-js";

// add an item to the list
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("My List").items.add({
    Title: "Title",
    Description: "Description"
}).then((iar: ItemAddResult) => {
    console.log(iar);
});
```

OR

Call REST api in your SPFx solution to save the data to SharePoint list.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('list title')/items
```

Demo:

```
private _makePOSTRequest(): void {

    const spOpts: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
      body: `{ Title: 'Developer Workbench', BaseTemplate: 100 }`
    };

    this.context.spHttpClient.post(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, spOpts)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        // Access properties of the response object. 
        console.log(`Status code: ${response.status}`);
        console.log(`Status text: ${response.statusText}`);

        //response.json() returns a promise so you get access to the json in the resolve callback.
        response.json().then((responseJSON: JSON) => {
          console.log(responseJSON);
        });
      });
}
```

Refer [demo here](https://www.vrdmn.com/2016/08/making-post-request-to-sharepoint-from.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to know if there is an another way than a sharepoint list for storing only one raw of data